# join multiple columns with no relation between them

Tags: mysql

I have two tables chat_list and alias. 
Fields of chat_list are id,counsellor_id,patient_id,chat_id and fields of alias table are id, counsellor_id,patient_id,patient_name. There is no relation between these two tables. Now I want data where chat_list.counsellor_id=alias.counsellor_id and chat_list.patient_id=alias.patient_id where chat_list.counsellor_id=? But I am geting duplicate records. I used DINSTINCT for that. But it is also not working. Is there any other way in mysql for this?

chat_list table
[chat_list table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVdVA.png)
alias table 
[alias table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oh882.png)

Query: SELECT c.chat_id,a.patient_name from chat_list as c INNER JOIN alias as a ON c.counseller_id= a.counseller_id and c.patient_id= a.patient_id WHERE c.counseller_id=?

Answer from query:[answer from query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRUZR.png)

Answer I want:[answer I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvDCz.png)

Comment: It would be a lot more clear if you can include the SQL with DISTINCT in the way you are trying it.

Comment: A targeted group by, the distinct probably would have worked but there is something that is different which gives you the duplicates.

Comment: I have tired group by for this also.

Comment: Please re-format your question and also show us what you did. Display some sample records from the table and then also the exact query that you used.

Comment: I used group by but I am getting incorrect answer from that query. Can you please provide me the query?

Comment: We can't give an answer if you don't provide us enough information. Please, can you edit your question and add table structures, records, and the results you are expecting from the query ?

Comment: I have edited it can you please check it and give me the solution?

Comment: Not seeing a duplicate, unless you are talking about patient id 30?  It has a totally different chat id.

Comment: I want first,third and last data from query result.

Comment: It's still unclear what you are trying to achieve. What result do you want? Why there is two patients with the same id? You said you want first, third and last data but we only have 3 entries! You need to clarify your problem so that we can help you.

Comment: In my answer I got same chat id with two entries. But I want one chat id with one patient name. Patient _id are same but there is difference between status in chat_list table.  Let me give you the answer I want..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.chat_id, a.patient_name , c.counseller_id
FROM chat_list as c INNER JOIN alias as a 
ON c.counseller_id= a.counseller_id 
AND c.patient_id= a.patient_id 
AND c.counseller_id='Your id here'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this query gives me the same answer.

Comment: Are you sure your chat_list table has single entry for each chat_id for each patient? Can we have screenshot of original table?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your additional details, here is the query you're looking for

```
SELECT c.chat_id, a.patient_name , c.counseller_id
FROM chat_list as c INNER JOIN alias as a 
ON c.counseller_id= a.counseller_id 
AND c.patient_id = a.patient_id 
AND c.id = a.id
WHERE c.counseller_id = 18
```